# How do I lookup two fields against same (foreign) table

Tags: mysql, sql

(MySQL) I have two tables:

```
|------------|      |------------|
| LOANS      |      |PEOPLE      |
|------------|      |------------|
|lenderID    |      |personID    |
|borrowerID  |      |firstName   |
|LibrarianID |      |lastname    |
|------------|      |------------|
```

In the loans table, everyone of those fields refers to a matching personID in the PEOPLE table.

What I'm looking for is a single SQL query statement something like

```
SELECT
   CONCAT(firstName, " ", lastname) as TheLender,
   CONCAT(firstName, " ", lastname) as TheBorrower,
   CONCAT(firstName, " ", lastname) as TheLibrarian,
FROM
   ...
WHERE   
   ...
```

I can't workout how to get all three names in a single result. How do I iterate through three links, firstly on lenderID = personID, then borrowerID = personId, and then librarianID=personID.... all in one go?

Comment: Have you tried to use `AND` operator to do it in a single result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join PEOPLE multiple time something as

```
select 
concat(lend.firstName, " ", lend.lastname) as TheLender,
concat(borr.firstName, " ", borr.lastname) as TheBorrower,
concat(libr.firstName, " ", libr.lastname) as TheLibrarian
from 
LOANS l 
join PEOPLE lend on lend.personID = l.lenderID
join PEOPLE borr on borr.personID = l.borrowerID
join PEOPLE libr on libr.personID = l.LibrarianID
where ....
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks mate. Taught me a few things there.

Comment: You are most welcome , and glad it helped and made you learn few things :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.Name,y.Name,z.Name FROM
```

(SELECT firstName, " ", lastname  as Name , personID from ... where personID = TheLenderID ) as x join (SELECT firstName, " ", lastname  as Name , personID from ... where personID = TheBorrowerID) as y join (SELECT firstName, " ", lastname  as Name , personID from ... where personID = TheLibrarianID) as z

This is Microsoft-SQL, but the idea should be the same for mysql, you have to do 3 subqueries for each type of person you have and join them. This is my solution, hope it helps.